# Explanation of two things regarding $\Bbb{F}_{p^r}$ and $\Bbb Q_p$

Tags: field-theory, definition, p-adic-number-theory

Can someone explain the following excerpt to me:

> In fact, all $\Bbb F_{p^r}$ together form the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$.

and tell me what $\Bbb Q_p$ is? I am aware of the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$, but not of $\Bbb Q_p$.

---

The first was said, and the latter was written in a talk I went to months ago, and I was just looking through the notes I took.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ is an integral domain, and $\mathbb Q_p$ is its associated field. You can also think of it as $\mathbb Z_p\left[\frac 1p\right].$

Answer (score 2):

In the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ of $\mathbb F_p$, you have one subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ for each $k$, namely:

$$A_k=\{x\in  \overline{\mathbb F_p}\mid x^{p^k}=x\}$$

Since there are no repeated roots to $x^{p^k}-x$ (why?) and the polynomial splits in $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$, you must have $p^k$ distinct roots. Show that they form a field, and hence $A_k\cong\mathbb F_{p^k}.$

Now, ever element of $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ is the root of some irreducible polynomial of degree, say, $k$, but then that element must be in $A_k\cong \mathbb F_{p^k}.$ So every element of $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ is in some $A_k.$ So $\overline{\mathbb F_p}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k.$

---

$\mathbb Q_p$ are the $p$-adic numbers. They can be considered as any of:

1. The field of fractions of $\mathbb Z_p.$
2. $\mathbb Z_p\left[\frac 1p\right].$
3. The completion of $\mathbb Q$ under a certain metric that extends the $p$-adic metric on $\mathbb Z.$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the field of $p$-adic numbers, which is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (or if you prefer, the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value). The highlighted statement is just the fact that
$$ \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p=\bigcup_{r\geq 1}\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$$

Comment: Well, union might be the wrong symbol, but it is roughly the case.

Comment: Disjoint union, or some sort of inverse limit, or some sort of infinite transcendence degree extension or something?

Comment: It's a bit of an abuse of notation, but we can imagine that I have fixed some algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Well, it’s a direct limit, and if you wish, you have $\Bbb F_{p^{1!}}\subset\Bbb F_{p^{2!}}\subset\Bbb F_{p^{3!}}\subset\dots$, and the algebraic closure is the union here.